# manual folding of latex using vim-latex

Tags: plugin-vim-latex

In my `vimrc`, for `vim-latex-suite` I have used (as described [here](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/documentation/latex-suite/customizing-what-to-fold.html#Tex_FoldedMisc))

```
  let g:Tex_FoldedMisc = 'preamble,!!!'
```

with the expectation that it will fold the text inside

```
\noindent{%!!!
....
%!!!
```

I won't like to use the default `<<<`, as  for my other setup, `<<` is mapped to `<>`, and hence trying `!!!`.

But this is not working. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the documentation for `Tex_FoldedMisc` that you linked to:

> Unlike the other `Tex_FoldedXXXX` variables, the words in this setting are **limited to take values from the following list**.

And while the list includes `preamble` and `<<<`, it doesn't include other triplets of symbols such as `!!!`.

The documentation seems quite explicit that `<<<` (with the corresponding `>>>`) is the only set actually supported by this option, using a different symbol will just not work.

Comment: oh...sure! its even more explicit with "Any other words in the Tex_FoldedMisc setting are silently ignored." Somehow I missed it, with the first line as `default value is`.